# набор текста в textarea

Tags: style, textarea, resize

Добрый день. Для `texarea` есть стандартные стили для `resize`, что позволяет ограничивать тег по горизонтали или по вертикали. У меня есть `textarea`, которая будет ограничена по горизонтали и свободная по вертикали. Прошу помочь с таким вопросом: можно ли сделать так, чтобы когда мы набираем текст в `texarea` - текст раздвигал по вертикали саму `textarea`?

Comment: Возможно Вам подойдет подобный [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height).

Comment: @Nikita Kazantsev, такой вариант, к сожалению, не подойдёт. Здесь textarea, когда вводишь текст - не раздвигает texarea никак(

Comment: [Автоматическое изменение размера `textarea` при вводе](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=2&id=1339)

Comment: Да, оно. спс @Андрей